# Generate Markdown from template

Tags: node.js, markdown, pandoc

I'd like to use the `node-pandoc` module to generate PDFs from Markdown. But I need to create those Markdowns on fly. Are there any templating engines for node.js that can generate plaintext/markdown?

Comment: Pandoc can not only parse Markdown, but also (subsets of) HTML, DocBook XML, etc. which might be easier to generate.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently used [underscore](http://underscorejs.org)'s `template` with plain text files written in [rho](https://npmjs.org/package/rho) (which is also a plain-text-to-html tool, like Markdown) to generate plain text documents with dynamic data:

Here's the code of my module (omit the caching if you don't need it):

```
// compiler.js
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path')
  , _ = require('underscore');

var cache = {};

exports.getTemplate = function(templateId, cb) {
  // Use your extension here
  var file = path.join(__dirname, templateId + ".rho");
  fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    // Try to get it from cache
    var cached = cache[templateId];
    if (cached && cached.mtime >= stat.mtime)
      return cb(null, cached.template);
    // Read it from file
    fs.readFile(file, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      // Compile it
      var template = _.template(data);
      // Cache it
      cache[templateId] = {
        mtime: stat.mtime,
        template: template
      };
      // Return it
      return cb(null, template);
    });
  });
};

exports.compile = function(templateId, data, cb) {
  exports.getTemplate(templateId, function(err, template) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    try {
      return cb(null, template(data));
    } catch (e) {
      return cb(e);
    }
  });
}
```

Now the usage. Assume you have `hello.rho` with following contents:

```
# Hello, <%= name %>!

We are happy to have you here, <%= name %>!
```

You can compile it like this:

```
require('./compiler').compile('hello', { name: 'World' }, function(err, text) {
  if (err) // Handle the error somehow
    return console.log(err);
  console.log(text);
  // You'll get "# Hello, World!\n\nWe're happy to have you here, World!"
  // Now chain the compilation to rho, markdown, pandoc or whatever else.
});
```

If you don't like underscore, then I guess [ejs](https://npmjs.org/package/ejs) would also do the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [grunt-readme](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-readme), which - although focused on generating README documentation from templates - is a good example of how you can generate markdown docs from templates.